# Create droppable area that can accept random text/images

Tags: jquery, droppable

I'm trying to create a droppable area that can accept random text, images, or text and images.

I know how to create a droppable in jQuery, but it only accepts items that are explicitly declared draggable. All I want to do is highlight random text, images, or text and images using my mouse in the browser and drag it (imagine highlighting this parenthesized statement and dragging it - no need for an actual draggable) over to the droppable area.

How can I create a droppable area that accepts random things and can give me information about what is being dropped into them?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

I think this May Help you!

By giving the same "Class" to all dragable elements you can achieve you goal.

Js:

```
$(function() {

    var $gallery = $('#something'), $trash = $('#divAccept');

    $('.drop',$gallery).draggable({
        revert: 'invalid', 
        containment: $('#divAccept').length ? '#divAccept' : 'document', 
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
    });

    $trash.droppable({
        accept: '#something > .drop',
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            deleteImage(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

    // image deletion function
    function deleteImage($item) {
            $item.fadeOut(function() {
                $item.appendTo($trash).fadeIn();
            });
    }
});
```

Html:

```
    <div id="something">
      <div class="drop">random text</div>
      <div class="drop"><img src="../images.jpeg" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="divAccept"></div>
```

[JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is can give you better guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to detect mouse events and dynamically make the content draggable ...

You can get the selected text using:

txt = document.getSelection();

It looks like this only works on text, not the actual HTML though.

Full selection code is here: http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp